# How to allocate the space without changing address in cpp?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

for example I have a struct now

```
struct TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
  TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

I first have a pointer, but I do not allocate space for it, so just

```
TreeNode* p;
```

I want to allocate the space later, for example, in the other function, like below

```
void allo(TreeNode* p, int val){
  p = new TreeNode(val);
}
allo(p,5);
// I want to get the original p here
```

But this `new` method change the address of the original `p`, which I could not trace it anymore. So is there a method to allocate without changing the address? The limitation is that I want to separate the definition and the allocation, just like above, for example, define outside a function and allocate inside the function.

Comment: `new` will not change the address nor the value of the original `p`, it will change the value of another local variable `p` which will be lost forever upon returning from the function. So you should either return pointer from function and assign it to `p` or take a pointer by reference. See [Where should I prefer pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](/questions/4986341/where-should-i-prefer-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Your code has a memory leak. Try `void allo(TreeNode*& p,int val)`

Comment: @all, I think your answers are all correct. The intuition of this question is just because that, it is valid for `void func(int* arr)` to change the value in `arr` array. So I guess the reason it works is because the `[]` overloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter by reference, if you want to manage this pointer outside this function. Otherwise a copy of the pointer is passed to the function `allo`. This copying changes the pointer.

Try like this (if I understand the essence of the question):

```
void allo(TreeNode*& ptr, int val)
{
    ptr = new TreeNode(val);
}
```

Comment: one thing I am still confused, before the `new` operation, the `p` address is the same with the one outside the function, if it is a copy, how could it have the same address? I think it means address but not value because it is hexadecimal 0x....

Comment: @Litchy Probably it's not an address, it's a value of pointer; To see address of pointer in debugger you should watch **&ptr**, not simple **ptr**

Comment: I see, so it is just like `TreeNode* p = parameter_p`, and once it is operated by `new`, its value is rand again and has no more connection with the outside `p`

Comment: @Litchy It "has connection" only if passed in function by reference not by value: void allo(TreeNode*& ptr, int val); "&" means reference, so ptr inside function is a reference to ptr outside.
When you write _ptr = new TreeNode(val);_ the address of ptr not changing, only value. But "connection" to outside defined by address, not by value

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

You should NOT use raw owning pointers but smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>` or RAII containers.

Your function `allo()` will do nothing to the pointer you pass to it because it takes the pointer by value (copy) and there is no way `allo()` could magically alter the adress of the pointer you pass it nor it's value. All that gets changed is the value of the parameter `p` which is local to your function, so the memory allocated effectively leaks.

Either, pass the paramter by reference so it can be altered within the function:

```
void allo(TreeNode* &ptr, int val)
{
    ptr = new TreeNode(val);
}

TreeNode *p{ nullptr };  // you shouldn't leave pointers uninitialized

// ...

allo(p, 42);
```

or return a value:

```
TreeNode* allo(int val)
{
    return new TreeNode(val);
}

// ...

TreeNode *p{ nullptr };

// ...

p = allo(42);
```

In both cases `p` points to the object allocated in `allo()` after the function call.

Comment: these two examples are excellent, by the way I gave the credit to the new contributor. lol, this is also a perfect answer.